# Assuming $ f(x) = 1/\ln(x) $, plot $ \int f(x) \mathrm dx $ on (1, 5)

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

> Assume $ f(x) = 1/\ln(x) $. Plot $ \int f(x) \mathrm dx $ on (1, 5)

How can I make a plot even though $ x=1 $ could be zero in the denominator?

Comment: Try and you will see, how nicely it works.

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SE! Perhaps you should check out functions `Assuming`, `Plot`, `Integrate` to get you started. Feel free to share your attempt with us (by editing your post) and we will be happy to help you with more specific issues.

Comment: Actually, are you even sure, that your question has anythign to do with *Mathematica*, the software? Or perhaps you need assitstance from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch. I don't see how it would work at all, since $\int_{1}^{x} f(u) du$ doesn't converge any $x$ and that is what I think the OP wants to plot.

Comment: @m_goldberg My reading was that OP wanted to plot the indefinite integral.

Comment: Seems like a homework problem.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
Integrate[1/Log[x], x]

(* LogIntegral[x]  *)
```

is the antiderivative. Let is plot it from 1 to 3:

```
Plot[LogIntegral[x], {x, 1.01, 3}]
```

[image]

The difference to the bill s answer is just because he plotted the definite and I plot the indefinite integral. The latter can be brought to the former:

```
Plot[LogIntegral[4] - LogIntegral[x], {x, 1.01, 3}]
```

[image]

Have fun

Answer (score 2):

$\def\li{\mathop{{\rm li}}}
 \def\op{{\int dx/\log x}}$

As a homework problem, the standard thing to do is to relate it to another one, perhaps simpler, that you know something about.  One of the cool things about $\log x$ is that it is concave down and therefore lies below its tangent $y = x-1$ at the $x$ intercept:

```
Plot[{x - 1, Log[x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore we can relate the following as integrands:
$${1 \over x-1} < {1 \over \log x}$$
Therefore the plot of $\op$ is steeper than the graph of $\int dx/(x-1) = \log(x-1)$ (plus an arbitrary constant).

So by picking some point to start at, say $(2,0)$, one could sketch (by hand) the graph of $y = \op$ on top of a graph of $y=\log(x-1)$, shown here as a *Mathematica* plot (the function $\li x \buildrel {\rm def} \over = \int_0^x dt/\log t$ is one antiderivative, called `LogIntegral[x]` in *Mathematica*):

```
Plot[{Log[x - 1], LogIntegral[x] - LogIntegral[2]}, {x, 1, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another interesting relationship between $\log(x-1)$ and the integral of $1/\log x$ that arises from the tangency at $x=1$ mentioned at the top, is that the functions are asymptotic at $x=1$.  In fact, the difference
$\log x - \li x$ approaches the [Euler constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html) $\gamma$:

```
Limit[LogIntegral[x] - Log[x - 1], x -> 1, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
(*  EulerGamma  *)
```

This means that there is an antiderivative $\op$ whose difference with $\log x$ approaches zero at the vertical asymptote at $x = 1$.  Again the graph of $y = \op$ will be steeper than $y = \log x$, but it's a nice relationship to illustrate:

```
Plot[{Log[x - 1], LogIntegral[x] - EulerGamma}, {x, 1, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

As @m.goldberg points out, you cannot do the integral from 1 to 4 because the integral at 1 does not converge. However, you can get arbitrarily close to 1 to get an idea what is happening. For example:

```
int = Table[{y, Integrate[1/Log[x], {x, y, 4}]}, {y, 4, 1.01, -0.03}];
ListLinePlot[int]
```

[image]